# Actions/animations interference

Tags: animation

I've created a simple mesh (a cube) and two simple animations for it.

First animation - cube going up and down (its location was adjusted and keyframed).
Second animation, an modified copy of the first one - cube rotating back and forth (location and rotation were keyframed).

Then I pausing the second animation in the middle, so that cube is rotated for an angle, and switch action to the first one. Cube rotation still applied. It moving up and down normally, but it also has rotation left from second animation, from particular frame where it was paused.

Is it expected behaviour? Because I expected, if there is no keyframes on particular transformation, then it must be set to some default value, not captured from another animation current state.

Also, this effect is additive - if several actions exists which using different transformations, then switching between them make the model to be a total irreversible mess.

What have I do wrong?

Comment: What keying set do you use, when keyframing the object for each actions? If it's *LocRot*, the rotation channel is keyframed, too, even if only the location is changed.

Comment: I used Location and Rotation keyframes. Well yes, LocRotScale will solve the problem, but is it ever normal behaviour?

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behavior. Un-keyframed channel doesn't revert to some default value.